# How to cast date time to snowflake timestamp while copying data from a external stage in to a table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to copy data from the external stage(azure) to a table in snowflake

The file format is in csv which include a date columns- orderdate('2/24/2003 0:00') .

I created table - sales_order  with a data type 'timestamp' for the column 'orderdate'

#csv file for sales_order

```
| sales    | orderdate     |
| -------- | --------------|
| 2871     | 2/24/2003 0:00|
| 3211     | 2/25/2003 0:00|
```

i used below copy command to copy data from external stage to the table

```
copy into sales_order  (sales, orderdate) from (select t.$1, to_timestamp_ntz(t.$2) from @sales_stage t)
```

But copying failed with below error

```
Timestamp '2/24/2003 0:00' is not recognized
```

#Expected

Any solution to load/transform the orderdate to the respective date time format in snowflake?

Comment: you still need to format the date!

Answer (score 0):

The format of the orderdate column needs to have the proper time information like

If you try to add the seconds info in the Orderdata column and try to convert, it should work
Your oderdate column should look like this
| sales    | orderdate     |
| -------- | --------------|
| 2871     | 2/24/2003 00:00:00|
| 3211     | 2/25/2003 00:00:00|

If you try to do a data conversion with your specified data format it will fail

You can try this simple code to test
select to_timestamp_ntz('2/24/2003 0:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
Fails with error - Can't parse '2/24/2003 0:00' as timestamp with format 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

and if you now try this code
select to_timestamp_ntz('2/24/2003 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
This works.